# Birthday Registration Form Trouple

Tags: php

hello I'm trying to make a registration form for my website http://social.nssgaming.com/ but i got a error in the registration form. and i don't know what's wrong. i wont 3 boxes where you can se date, moth, and year. register.php is located here: http://paste2.org/a31FJE5L you can se the part of birthday in the index file here: (it's also saying the it missing some values in the form, and i think its in the birthday registration)

```
<?php

function GetMonthString($n){
$timestamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, $n, 1, 2010);
return date("F", $timestamp);
}

$display .= '</select>
<select name="year" class="birthday_btn" id="year">
<option value="">- Year -</option>';

$thisyear = date('Y');
$now = $thisyear - 1;
$end = $thisyear - 100 ;

for ($now; $now >= $end; $now--) {
if ($_POST['year'] == $now){
$display .= '<option value="'.$now.'" selected>'.$now.'</option>';
}
else{
$display .= '<option value="'.$now.'" >'.$now.'</option>';
}
}
$display .= '</select> ';

$display .='</select>
<select name="month" class="birthday_btn" id="month">
<option value="" >- Month -</option>';
for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) {
if ($_POST['month'] == $i){
$display .= '<option value="'.$i.'" selected>'.GetMonthString($i).'</option>';
}
else{
$display .= '<option value="'.$i.'" >'.GetMonthString($i).'</option>';
}
}


$display .= '</select>
<select name="day" class="birthday_btn" id="day">
<option value="'.$i.'" >- Day -</option>';

for ($i = 1; $i <= 31; $i++) {
if ($_POST['day'] == $i){
$display .= '<option value="'.$i.'" selected>'.$i.'</option>';
}
else{
$display .= '<option value="'.$i.'" >'.$i.'</option>';
}
}
$display .= '</select> ';

echo $display;
?>
```

and in localhost i got those errors:

Birthday

Notice: Undefined variable: display in C:\xampp\htdocs\social\index.php on line 237

Notice: Undefined index: year in C:\xampp\htdocs\social\index.php on line 244

Notice: Undefined index: month in C:\xampp\htdocs\social\index.php on line 257

Notice: Undefined index: day in C:\xampp\htdocs\social\index.php on line 271

Comment: possible duplicate of [birthday registration form trouble](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26433836/birthday-registration-form-trouble)

Comment: @seane the question on the supposed duplicate link is not solved

Answer (score 0):

You should use `isset( $_POST['name'] )` before retrieving the value, like so:

```
$foo = null;
if( isset( $_POST['foo'] ) {
    $foo = $_POST['foo'];
}
```

I have my own simple helper-function to simplify this:

```
function get( $collection, $key ) {
    if( isset( $collection[ $key ] ) ) return $collection[ $key ];
    return null;
}
```

thus:

```
 $year = get( $_POST, 'year' );
```

Comment: can you edit it into the document? because i don't know exactly what you mean